# Firebase Logged Events are visible in DebugView but not in Firebase Events

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I'm on a React Native Project and I'm using Firebase Analytics v21.2.0

The Issue I was facing was that several of my Logged Events were missing on Production.

To test this, I tried to log some test events. These test events are visible in DebugView Section of Firebase but they don't show up in the Events Panel. I've also waited for more than a day for them to show up and I have logged these test events, both with and without setting my app as the Debug App for Firebase that is required for the events to show up in DebugView.